# Use Huawei E8231 as a 3g modem

Tags: gentoo, 3g, usb-modeswitch

I'm using Gentoo, and I have a problem with the 3g modem Huawei E8231. As far as I understand, to make it work I should switch its mode:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:572a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131 (Mass storage mode) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -V 12d1 -p 1f01 -P 14db -M "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000101000100000000000000" 

$ lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:572a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# dmesg 

[19469.255798] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd 
[19469.396894] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f01 
[19469.396898] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
[19469.396900] usb 1-3: Product: HUAWEI Mobile 
[19469.396901] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI 
[19469.396903] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 
[19469.397809] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected 
[19469.397868] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0 
[19470.397691] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM HUAWEI Mass Storage 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 
[19470.470961] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive 
[19470.471189] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0 
[19470.471320] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5 
[19591.778652] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 11 
[19592.095020] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd 
[19592.238652] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14db 
[19592.238655] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
[19592.238658] usb 1-3: Product: HUAWEI Mobile 
[19592.238659] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI 
[19592.311677] cdc_ether 1-3:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00

# usb-devices 

T: Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 12 Spd=480 MxCh= 0 
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=02(commc) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1 
P: Vendor=12d1 ProdID=14db Rev=01.02 
S: Manufacturer=HUAWEI 
S: Product=HUAWEI Mobile 
C: #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA 
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_ether 
I: If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_ether
```

It seems that everything is ok, but there aren't any new devices or interfaces:

```
$ ls /dev | grep ttyUSB #empty result 


$ ifconfig #no usb0 

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 
ether c4:54:44:b2:ca:45 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) 
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) 
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) 
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0 

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host> 
loop txqueuelen 0 (Local Loopback) 
RX packets 9445 bytes 5167034 (4.9 MiB) 
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 
TX packets 9445 bytes 5167034 (4.9 MiB) 
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0 

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 
inet 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255 
inet6 fe80::fa16:54ff:fe6e:2940 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link> 
ether f8:16:54:6e:29:40 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) 
RX packets 875123 bytes 1243972975 (1.1 GiB) 
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 
TX packets 391840 bytes 42394343 (40.4 MiB) 
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Wat's wrong?

*note: I also asked this question on [gentoo forum](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1031456-highlight-.html)*

Comment: On Windows, those devices tend to appear as a mass storage (first case) or USB CDROM (after modeswitch) containing the real driver plus the modem.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 I'm not sure, how this can help me?

Comment: Forget it. According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem#Mode_switching) it looks like there's really some mode-switching magic on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this modem had it's link at the `eth1`, so I managed to make it work using this commands:

```
# ifconfig eth0 down
# ifconfig eth1 up
# dhcpcd
```